# Application returning 504

Tags: node.js, heroku, adonis.js

I have an adonis app (api rest) hosted inside heroku with 4 nodes of 1gb each.
For some reason queries to this app return random 504 errors, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.
The worst of all this is that in the heroku logs these 504 requests do not appear, and not even in the new relic.

Any idea what it could be?!

[image][image]

Comment: 504 is HTTP Gateway Timeout error

Comment: yes, but is this an error at the application level? because on heroku i don't have accesses to the server.

Comment: It's a Proxy server error